# NetBeans - how to open Chromium open source project with netbeans?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, netbeans

For community, i have this project compiled/build/released manually using NotePad++ but its very difficult to work for such large project with just one text editor.

I want to use the large project with my favourite NetBeans IDE, to get fast coding done and use some tools of NetBeans while coding that i love. 
(but build / compile/ release i can do manually as usual)

How can i open the whole project in NetBeans IDE? 
i have this source code located in my path `C:\folder\chromium\src`

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/45.0.2438.2

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough if you just create an new Project within Netbeans and choose creating **Project with Existing Sources** as type of your project. Netbeans will ask you where did you store the existing sources which you  just need to tell it and tada you can start coding

Here is an link where it is described via picture. It's not exactly what you asked for but you see the process of how to open a project you just need to change the type they choose in that tutorial.

[How to open an new Project](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html)